# Does the existence of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_1^n f(x)dx $ imply convergence of$\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ if $f$ is decreasing?

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Prove or provide counter example:
If $f$ is monotonically decreasing and if $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_1^n f(x)dx $ exists ($n$ denotes a positive integer), then the integral $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ converges.

I was wondering if $f$ is positive then from the integral test the partial sums of $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)$ are bounded above implying convergence of $\sum f(n)$, therefore convergence of$\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ (If I got it right).

A) Is there an example of $f$ being nonpositive decreasing  and  $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_1^n f(x)dx $ exists?

B) The existence of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_1^n f(x)dx $ always implies that $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ converges (for any continuous function)?

Comment: If $f(x_0)<0$, then $f(x)<f(x_0)=c<0,\,\forall x>x_0$, so $$\int_{x_0}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx<\int_{x_0}^\infty c\,\mathrm dx=-\infty$$

Comment: Also, isn't that the definition of an improper integral?
 $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^nf(x)\,\mathrm dx=:\int_1^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx$$ So if that limit exists the so does the integral?

Comment: Excuse me ,my fault n denotes a positive integer!

Comment: That's fine - if the limit exists, then it doesn't matter how you take the limit - via positive integers will still give the same limit.

Comment: I was wandering the same thing but I am not sure.If the limit exists for n it exists for all $b\ge 1$?

Comment: What is $b{}{}$?

Comment: Then if the sequence $I(n)=\int_1^n f(x)dx $ converges,  the improper integral converges too?

Comment: let b any real number.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Also, I don't see where $b$ is mentioned anywhere...

Comment: Yes I am sorry,I first  mentioned it in the comment without defining it.Thank you for answering and excuse my confusion !!!

Comment: Edit:$ I(b)=\int_1^b f(x)dx $let b any real number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\int_1^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$ converges, that is, $\lim\limits_{y\to\infty} \int_1^y f(x)\,dx$ where $y\in [1,\infty)$ exists, then of course the limit of the "subsequence" $\int_1^n f(x)\,dx$ exists, and is the same. This direction holds without any conditions on $f$ (other than integrability over all intervals $[1,y]$, which is required for the statement to even make sense).

If $f$ is nonnegative, then

$$I(y) = \int_1^y f(x)\,dx$$

is a monotonically increasing (not necessarily strictly) function. A monotonic function $M \colon [1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ has a limit at $\infty$ if and only if it is bounded, and since $M(y)$ lies between $M(n)$ and $M(n+1)$ (inclusive) for $y \in [n,n+1]$, boundedness of $M$ is then equivalent to boundedness of the sequence $\bigl(M(n)\bigr)_{n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}}$.

Thus for nonnegative $f$ (that is integrable over all intervals $[1,n]$), convergence of $\int_1^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$ is equivalent to convergence of the sequence $\bigl(\int_1^n f(x)\,dx\bigr)_{n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}}$.

If $f$ is monotonically decreasing, then $\int_1^y f(x)\,dx$ exists for all $y \in [1,\infty)$, and nonnegativity of $f$ is a *necessary* condition for the convergence of $\int_1^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$. For if there is a $z \in [1,\infty)$ with $c = f(z) < 0$, then for $x > z$ we have $f(x) \leqslant c$ and hence

$$\int_1^y f(x)\,dx = \int_1^z f(x)\,dx + \int_z^y f(x)\,dx \leqslant \int_1^z f(x)\,dx + (y-z)\cdot c \tag{$\ast$}$$

for $y \geqslant z$, and the right hand side of $(\ast)$ is not bounded from below.

Thus the answer to A) is "no". [Assuming that "existence of the limit" means existence in $\mathbb{R}$. If $\pm \infty$ are allowed as limits, then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int_1^n f(x)\,dx = -\infty$ for every monotonically decreasing $f \colon [1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ that attains a negative value somewhere, as follows from $(\ast)$.]

The answer to B) is also negative, to deduce the convergence of $\int_1^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$ from the existence of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_1^n f(x)\,dx$ we need additional assumptions like decay conditions ($\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$ suffices then) or nonnegativity. Consider $f(x) = \sin (2\pi x)$. Then

$$\int_1^n f(x)\,dx = 0$$

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_1^n f(x)\,dx$ exists. But

$$\int_1^{n + \frac{1}{2}} f(x)\,dx = \frac{1}{\pi}$$

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so $\lim\limits_{y\to\infty} \int_1^y f(x)\,dx$ doesn't exist.

Comment: I am very greatfull for this answer.It was extremely helpfull.

Comment: I hope I will understand better improper integrals.Thank you!

Comment: Good. If you get stuck, I can give you a hint or two.

Comment: I was hoping you would say that!

Comment: My attempt proving $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_1^n=\int_1^\infty f(x) dx$ if the limit of  f ends to zero as x tends to infinity:$|f(x)|<\epsilon$ for every $x \ge X$ and $ \int_1^n f(x)=A $ for large n, then , $| \int_1^b f(x) dx-A |=| \int_1^n f(x)dx-A+\int_n^b f(x) dx | \le |\int_1^n f(x) dx-A | +| \int_n^b f(x)dx|<k+\epsilon (b-n). $ for every $n\le x\le b \le(n+1)$ (k>0).I would appreciate some help!Thank you  in advance!

Comment: You are essentially there. Let's organise things to make it clear. First, we have $A=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^n f(x)\,dx$. (The existence of the limit is assumed, we just give a name to it here.) We want to show that $\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_1^b f(x)\,dx=A$, under the additional assumption $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$. So, for every $\varepsilon>0$, we need to find an $X$ such that $\bigl\lvert A-\int_1^b f(x)\,dx\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon$ for every $b\geqslant X$. By the first assumption, there is an $N$ such that $\bigl\lvert A-\int_1^n f(x)\,dx\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon/2$ for $n\geqslant N$.

Comment: By the second assumption, there is an $x_0$ such that $\lvert f(x)\rvert<\varepsilon/2$ for $x\geqslant x_0$. Then, let $X$ be an integer $\geqslant \max\:\{ N, x_0\}$. This $X$ works, because for $b\geqslant x$, if we choose $n=\lfloor b\rfloor$, then $n\geqslant X\geqslant N$, whence the first term in your split integral, $\bigl\lvert A - \int_1^n f(x)\,dx\bigr\rvert$, is $<\varepsilon/2$, and since $n\geqslant N\geqslant x_0$, we have $\lvert f(x)\rvert<\varepsilon/2$ on $[n,b]$, whence the second term is at most $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}(b-n)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ because $0\leqslant b-n<1$.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I was missing things which you made a lot clearer!