# If $f$ is monotonic decreasing and if $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n$ exists, where $I_n=\int_1^n f(t)dt$, then the integral $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

This is exercise 10.24.20 in Apostol, Calculus 1. The question has been asked before ([Does the existence of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_1^n f(x)dx $ imply convergence of$\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ if $f$ is decreasing?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461316/does-the-existence-of-lim-n-to-infty-int-1n-fxdx-imply-convergence-of)) but I don't think it is resolved there.

The following is my proof. Could you please check if it is correct.

We first prove that $f(x)$ has a fixed sign for all $x\geq c$ for some $c>1$. If there exists a $a>1$ such that $f(a)<0$, then $f(x)\leq f(a)<0$ for all $x\geq a$. Otherwise, assume no such $a$ exists. If there exists a $b>1$ such that $f(b)=0$, then $f(x)\leq f(b)=0$ for all $x\geq b$. But $f(x)$ cannot be negative (contradicting the hypothesis), we have $f(x)=0$ for all $x>b$. If there exists no such $b$, then $f(x)>0$ for all $x\geq 1$. Therefore there exists a positive integer $m\geq 1$, such that $x\geq m$ implies $f(x)$ has a fixed sign.

We now consider the three cases:
(i) If $f(x)=0$ for $x\geq m$, then $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ converges, since $\int_m^\infty f(x)dx=0$.

(ii) If $f(x)<0$ for $x\geq m$, then $f(x)\leq f(m)<0$. For $n\geq m$, $I_n-I_m=\int_m^n f(x)dx\leq\int_m^n f(m)dx=(n-m)f(m)$ does not have a limit as $n\to+\infty$, contradicting that $\{I_n\}$ converges.

(iii) The only remaining possibility is $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$. $f$ is monotonic decreasing with a lower bound, so $L=\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)$ exists. If $L>0$, then $I_n=\int_1^n f(x)dx>\int_1^n Ldx=L(n-1)$ does not have a limit as $n\to\infty$, contradicting that $\{I_n\}$ converges. Therefore $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=0$. Thus $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ converges, by exercise 10.24.21.

The content of exercise 10.24.21 is: If $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n=A$, then $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ converges and has the value $A$.

Proof of exercise 10.24.21: Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n=A$, we could find a positive integer $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|I_n-A|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. On the other hand, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$, so there exists a real number $M>0$ such that $x>M$ implies $|f(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Now for all $x>\max(M,N)+1$, we have $[x]\geq M,N$, so $|I_{[x]}-A|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|f(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, so $|\int_1^x f(t)dt-A|=|I_{[x]}+\int_{[x]}^x f(t)dt-A|\leq|I_{[x]}-A|+|\int_{[x]}^x f(t)dt|\leq|I_{[x]}-A|+\int_{[x]}^x |f(t)|dt<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+(x-[x])\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$ (since $x-[x]<1$). Therefore $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\int_1^x f(t)dt=A$. Hence $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ converges and has the value $A$.

$[x]$ denotes the greatest integer satisfying $\leq x$.

Comment: In the first part of your proof, you wrote "If there exists a $a>1$ such that $f(a)<0$, then $f(x)\leq f(a)<0$ for all $x\geq a$. Otherwise, assume no such $a$ exists. If there exists a $b>1$ such that $f(b)=0$, then $f(x)\leq f(b)=0$ for all $x\geq b$. But $f(x)$ cannot be negative (**contradicting the hypothesis**), we have $f(x)=0$ for all $x>b$." What hypothesis does it contradict?

Comment: You may first verify that $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=\inf_{x\ge 1} f(x)=0$, by arguing $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=\inf_{x\ge 1} f(x)$ can neither be $-\infty$ or some positive number or negative number. Then $F(x):=\int_1^x f(u){\rm d}u$ is non-decreasing since $f\ge 0$. Then that $\lim_{n\to+\infty} F(n)$ exists implies $\lim_{x\to+\infty} F(x)$ exists.

Comment: @Asigan To your first question: the hypothesis refers to "assume no such $a$ exists", meaning no $a$ exists such that $f(a)<0$.

Comment: @Asigan Thank you for your comment. I did exactly what you said. I just spent a lot of words ((i) (ii) and (iii)) explaining that $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=0$.

Comment: To my first question (what hypothesis did it contradict): I admit this is my fault. I did not read your proof carefully. However, as for your proof you over complicated it. Your (iii) has proved that $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)\le 0$, and your (ii) has proved that it is *impossible* that exists $x_0$, $f(x_0)<0$, i.e. $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$. Taking limit (or inf) we yield $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)\ge 0$. Therefore $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)= 0$. You *do not need to* prove that $f$ has a fixed sign for some $x\ge c$ in the first paragraph.

Comment: Your proof works. Yes, it is more complicated than needed, but this is not unexpected. But I am curious what your issue is with the answer to the linked question. It seems to me to cover the matter adequately.